# How can i move the cursor position to a position that I want

Tags: wpf, vb.net

After i move the mouse I want to move the mousepointer to his original position.
How can i move the cursor position to a position that i want.

```
  Private Sub MoveCursor(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)  

  Me.Cursor = New Cursor  
  Cursor.Position = New Point(Cursor.Position.X - 50, Cursor.Position.Y - 50)  

  End Sub
```

Comment: Setting mouse position in Windows.Forms is something else then in WPF

Answer (score 1):

Settings mouse position in WPF is not possible (as far as I know) so you have to use Windows.Forms or setcursorpos from user32.dll